# document.getElementById().value isn't current

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

In a form on a specific site (others work), there's an

```
<input type=text value="1">
```

Update the value to "3", without submitting the form, and go to Chrome's console.

```
document.getElementById('updates_959338052').value
```

returns 1. Also $("..").val()

Can't figure out why it's not working on this site. To replicate:
http://365nailart.com/products/essie-nail-polish-all-in-one?variant=959338052
click Add to cart, the My Cart and Checkout. Then change the quantity value.

After a few WTFs and googling, I'm kindly asking for help.

Comment: instead of giving website url post relevent code here plz...not able to unerstand what you actually want.

Comment: If for some reason the linked website goes down, or changes, this question will become useless. So, post everything that's relevant as part of your question.

Comment: Anyway... On my browser console it's working. It's showing me the changed value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.prop() vs .attr()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `input` elements with the same id. The id in html document must be unique. When you try to do `document.getElementById('updates_959338052')`, it is selecting the first one which is not the one displayed, maybe from mobile compatible part of your website.